# iOs jump the fixed footer that is containing INPUT

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, cordova

I am having a phoneGap-cordova application. In which I have a page that has a fixed footer for input , but whenever a soft key (keyboard) opens in the mobile, the fixed element looses its position and jump upwards,

I have seen a lot of solutions for the same but no luck .

here is my css for the page :

```
.main {
  display: table;
  border-spacing:0px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: auto;
   }

.imageIcon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contentDiv {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left:12px;
  width:100%;
}
.nameAndId {
  /* background-color: aqua; */
  margin-top:6px;
  font-family: Roboto-medium;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.commentDetails {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.ID
{
    font-size: 12px;
    display:inline;
}
.updateTime {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 16px;
  font-family: Roboto-light;
    font-size: 12px;
  color:#767676;
}

.footerClass
{   background:#ffffff;
    position:device-fixed; 
    bottom:0px;
    padding: 16px 0px;  
    width:100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    }

.cameraImage
{

    width:initial;
    margin-left: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;


}

.inputComment
{

    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.inputCommentTextBox
{
    width:100%;
    outline: 0;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color:#767676;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;

}

.postImage
{

    width:initial;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;


}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="mainComment" style="background-color:#ffffff; height:auto;padding-top:1px; padding: 1px 0px 20px;overflow-x:hidden;" >
    <div style="background-color:#ededed;display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;">
        <div style="-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 100%;-ms-flex:1 100%;flex:1 100%;text-align: center;-webkit-align-self: center;-ms-flex-item-align: center;align-self: center;padding-top:4px;padding-left: 20px;">Comments</div>
        <div class="cameraImage showPen"><img data-ng-click="returnBack()" style="width: 35px;height: 35px;padding: 10px;" src="close.png" alt="Camera Image"/></div>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-repeat="name in names" >

        <div  class="main" style="background:#ffffff;padding: 10px;">
            <div class="imageIcon"><img style="height:56px;width:56px;"src="user.png" alt="UserMale" /></div>
            <div class="contentDiv">        
                    <div class="nameAndId">{{name}},<p class="ID"> {{xyz}}</p></div>
                    <div class="commentDetails">{{abc}}</div>
                    <div class="updateTime timeago" title="" >{{yzk}} ago</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <div id="footerId" class="footerClass" >
            <div class="cameraImage showPen" data-ng-show="false"><img data-ng-click="returnBack()" style="width:20px;height:20px;" src="close.png" alt="Camera Image"/></div>
            <div class="inputComment"><input onfocus="this.value = this.value;" id="commentBox" data-ng-model="commentData" type="text" placeholder="Write your Comment" class="inputCommentTextBox"></div>  
            <div class="postImage"  data-ng-show='postSelector'><img  style="width:26px;height:22px;" src="send.png" alt="Search Image"/></div>
            <div class="postImage" data-ng-show='loadMoreContentComment'>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so whenever I get the focus on the input int the footer which is fixed It gets displaced from its position and go upward.

please suggest me solution, because I already went through a lot of solutions but no luck yet.

Thanks

Comment: `device-fixed`? Try to just use `fixed` and normal HTML statements like that.

Comment: @Sithys can you tell me exactly how to use that , because when I tried to use it as position:device-fixed; it is not working for me.

Comment: This seems to be a problem for iOS Chrome too.  But it's not consistent.  After interacting with the elements, the behavior changes and the floating element stops shifting.  At least in my case.  Making the position 'absolute' doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input").on("focus", function(event){
    if(event.handled !== true)
    {
        $(".footerClass").css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        $(".footerClass").css('display', 'none');        
    }
    return false;
});

$("input").on("blur", function(event){
   if(event.handled !== true)
   {        
      if(!$("input").is(":focus")){
          $(".footerClass").css({ 'position': 'fixed' })
          $(".footerClass").css('display', 'block');           
      }
   }
   return false;
});
```